# Delay On Assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to know how i can do delay (Timer) on assembler 16 bit on PC.
Thank You for helping,
Norm.

OS: Windows

CODE:

```
 delay:
     inc bx
     cmp bx,WORD ptr[time]
     je delay2
     jmp delay
 delay2:
     inc dx
     cmp dx,WORD ptr[time2]
     je delay3
     jmp delay
     mov bx,0
 delay3:
     inc cx
     cmp cx,WORD ptr[time3]
     je Finish_delay
     jmp delay
```

its not work good i need less complicated code

Comment: Did you just make a new account and ask *exactly* the same question as you did 10 minutes ago?  With no more information? BOOO.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016438

Comment: We need a lot more information if you want an answer - what architecture?  What OS or environment?  What code do you have already and what about it doesn't work?

Comment: edit your post to add the code.  The unformatted mess in the comment is useless.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858640/how-can-i-create-a-sleep-function-in-16bit-masm-assembly-x86) (*How can I create a sleep function in 16bit MASM Assembly x86?*).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you insert special NO-OP instructions? Or you can calculate a delay by inserting a branch instruction that is always mispredicted a certain number of times and multiplying that with the branch penalty of your architecture. That can be accurate +- 1 cycle.